# Server is not able boot /bin/sh no such file or directory

Tags: centos, redhat, centos5, kernel-panic

We have ldap server configuration in centos 5.8. Server is working fine yesterday as we today restarted the server its not able to boot. Gives following error :

> /bin/bash: ro : no such file or directory kernel panic- not synching:attempt to kill init

We tried to recover using rescue mode still no luck.

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
```

`/bin/sh` file is available in directory still it gives same error.

---

This is a capture of the console showing the issue.

[image]

This is the content of `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.el5 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.el5.img
```

Comment: It sounds like a problem either on kernel's command line or in the initial ramdisk. I suggest you to check the integrity of ramdisk files in `/boot/initrd-*.img`. Also, please could you capture an image showing console's output and the content of `/boot/grub/menu.lst`? While capturing the image, please ensure that `quiet` and `rhgb` command line arguments are absent.

Comment: @AndersonMedeirosGomes  

Image URL: https://imgur.com/fXr1dS1

Comment: The problem is not that `/bin/sh` does not exist, the problem is that `/bin/sh` tries to execute a binary named `ro` which doesn't exist. There is an error in your grub cmd line. Show your `grub.cfg` or `menu.lst` which you can find in `/boot/`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider

grub.cfg  and menu.lst is same.

"

default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.el5 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.el5.img  

"

File url : https://easyupload.io/89w063

Comment: @Rakesh Thank you. I see that the error message appears after the root partition is mounted and, possibly, after `/sbin/init` is executed. Therefore, the cause of the problem is not in grub or in the initial ramdisk. It looks like a filesystem issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the root filesystem was corrupted by an unclean shutdown and important files such as `/sbin/init`, `/bin/sh` and `/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit` were damaged somehow. I am not completely sure about it, though.

I suggest you to reinstall `bash`, `SysVinit` and `initscripts` packages using the image CD. Assuming that CDROM contents will be available through `/dev/hdb` device node in rescue mode, the reinstallation process can be performed by using the following steps:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
# mount /dev/hdb /mnt/cdrom
# rpm --root /mnt/sysimage -ivh --replacepkgs \
    /mnt/CentOS/{bash,SysVinit,initscripts}-*.rpm
```

Alternatively, by inspecting the file `/sbin/init`, `/etc/inittab` and files under the directory `/etc/rc.d`, you could figure out why `/sbin/init` is calling `/bin/sh` and, afterwards, calling a binary named `ro`. This does not look normal.

PS: `/bin/sh` should be a symbolic link pointing to `/bin/bash` and not a regular file.

---

**EDIT:** once there is a confirmation that `/sbin/init` executable does not exist in filesystem, I am sure that such absence is the cause of the problem. CentOS booting process is probably executing `/bin/sh` as fallback and passing `ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet` as command line arguments, thus leading `/bin/sh` to look for a script file named `ro`. Because it does not exist, `/bin/sh` throws the error message `ro: no such file or directory` and aborts.

I believe that reinstallation of the `SysVinit` package (which provides the `/sbin/init` executable) will fix the booting issue.

Comment: /sbin/init file is not available. How to recover or reinstall init file.

Comment: @Rakesh This is a very relevant information. Please, see my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you so much... able to boot now.

Comment: @Rakesh I am happy to help. I would also appreciate if you could signal that my answer had solved your problem by [accepting it](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers).